Android Studio - pubspec.yaml - supabase_flutter - Typo: In word 'supabase'?
I have
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  supabase_flutter: ^2.6.0

in my pubspec.yaml
I have used LLMs to edit it and I copied pasted it etc, but I am getting
Typo: In word 'supabase' 

Does anyone know how the heck to fix this issue

Since supabase is not a known word and if it bothers you that Android Studio notifies you about the spelling for it, you can add it to Android Studio.
You can go to Android Studio -> Settings -> Editor -> Spelling and then add it as an Accepted word.

You can also control the spelling inspection by going to Android Studio -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections and scroll down to Proofreading -> Typo

